# Azure Pipeline for SonarCloud analysis using Gradle is successful but no results are published

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I have tried to analyze a Java repository, build using Gradle wrapper, and publish the results in my SonarCloud organization.
I am using an Azure DevOps Pipeline for the build, however, I cannot see any results in the SonarCloud account, even though my pipeline build is successful.
I am using Sonarcloud Prepare task, Sonarcloud Run Analysis and Sonarcloud Publish, as well as Gradle build step with following settings:

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
  gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
  options: '-P offlineVersion=$(Build.SourceBranchName)-SNAPSHOT'
  tasks: 'publish'
  publishJUnitResults: true
  testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
  jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
  gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
  env:
  RUNONCI: 'true'
  REPO_USER_NAME: '$(RepoUserName)'
  REPO_USER_PASSWD: '$(RepoUserPasswd)'
  SNAPSHOTURL:

Could you please help me out?

I do not receive any error, only 2 warnings:

- When using Maven or Gradle, don't use the analyze task but instead tick the 'SonarQube' option in the Maven/Gradle task to run the scanner as part of the build.
- No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration.

My goal is to see the analysis results in the SonarCloud account. I have checked and the service connection I am using is verified and correct.